# using mysql option SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in JPA Criteria Query

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have a rather complex query here, where I also need to return the total of available result sets in addition to a limited result set.

There is the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in MySQL, which allows to return that number in a subsequent query by using an interceptor. I have already implemented this in a similar project, by using a hibernate with a native query and an interceptor and it worked fine.

However in this case, there already is this complex JPA Criteria query and I would be more than happy if I could add that mysql option to the criteria query, but couldn't find a way to do this so far.

Below are some details about how the entityManager and Criteria is set up

```
    @Stateless
    class Dao{
      @PersistenceContext(unitName = "persistenceName")
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
      public List<Entity> find(String someParam) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Entity> cq = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
        Root<Entity> root = cq.from(Entity.class);

        // some dummy predicate here
        cq.where(predicates);

        TypedQuery<Entity> query = this.entityManager.createQuery(cq);

        // limit query
        query.setFirstResult(100);
        query.setMaxResults(10);

        return query.getResultList();
      }
    }
```

Any ideas how to add the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option?
This thing runs in Glassfish 3 with Hibernate 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using eclipselink, and this fixed it for me:

```
query.setHint("eclipselink.sql.hint", "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS");
```

The eclipselink.sql.hint flag instructs the string to be added immediately after the first word in the query, in this case SELECT. There may be an equivalent for Hibernate.